# MongoDbUtils debug logging

Tags: spring, mongodb, logging

How can I disable the following logging from org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils:

DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[erepprod]

I have tried the following in my log4j.properties file:

log4j.category.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils=ERROR,console
log4j.logger.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils=ERROR,console

But the message is still being logged.

Any help would be appreciated as I have spent two days trying to get rid of this message.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but for anyone else having the problem,

I know from using Spring Boot that they seem to prefer now SL4J + [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html)
So by adding a logback.xml that looked like below.. solved it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework.data.mongodb">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```